# Apache Cloudstack Development Environment failed create Instance

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine, apache-cloudstack

I am trying to build build cloudstack 4.2 using my laptop by following this [guide](http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2014/02/test-apache-cloudstack-4-2-local-machine/) and, everything went smooth. But when I tried to create an instance I've got this following error :

```
WARN  [apache.cloudstack.alerts] (Job-Executor-1:job-11 = [ b3f84a36-095d-460d-a577-e8ef202cc218 ])  alertType:: 8 // dataCenterId:: 1 // podId:: null // clusterId:: null // message:: Failed to deploy Vm with Id: 5, on Host with Id: null
INFO  [user.vm.DeployVMCmd] (Job-Executor-1:job-11 = [ b3f84a36-095d-460d-a577-e8ef202cc218 ]) com.cloud.exception.InsufficientServerCapacityException: Unable to create a deployment for VM[User|3ce1dd42-8daf-43b8-891c-3c05827ff159]Scope=interface com.cloud.dc.DataCenter; id=1
INFO  [user.vm.DeployVMCmd] (Job-Executor-1:job-11 = [ b3f84a36-095d-460d-a577-e8ef202cc218 ]) Unable to create a deployment for VM[User|3ce1dd42-8daf-43b8-891c-3c05827ff159]
com.cloud.exception.InsufficientServerCapacityException: Unable to create a deployment for VM[User|3ce1dd42-8daf-43b8-891c-3c05827ff159]Scope=interface com.cloud.dc.DataCenter; id=1
    at org.apache.cloudstack.engine.cloud.entity.api.VMEntityManagerImpl.reserveVirtualMachine(VMEntityManagerImpl.java:209)
    at org.apache.cloudstack.engine.cloud.entity.api.VirtualMachineEntityImpl.reserve(VirtualMachineEntityImpl.java:198)
    at com.cloud.vm.UserVmManagerImpl.startVirtualMachine(UserVmManagerImpl.java:3412)
    at com.cloud.vm.UserVmManagerImpl.startVirtualMachine(UserVmManagerImpl.java:3000)
    at com.cloud.vm.UserVmManagerImpl.startVirtualMachine(UserVmManagerImpl.java:2986)
    at com.cloud.utils.component.ComponentInstantiationPostProcessor$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ComponentInstantiationPostProcessor.java:125)
    at org.apache.cloudstack.api.command.user.vm.DeployVMCmd.execute(DeployVMCmd.java:420)
    at com.cloud.api.ApiDispatcher.dispatch(ApiDispatcher.java:158)
    at com.cloud.async.AsyncJobManagerImpl$1.run(AsyncJobManagerImpl.java:531)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

This is happen when I create an Instance with Data Disk Offering enabled,
why is this happen? I want to test Cloudstack with complete functionality. Is there any suggestion what version of Cloudstack I should use?

Answer (score 1):

There is high probability that the **host on which you are trying to deploy the VM has not the required amount capacity**. You are saying that it fails while creating VM with data disk. **Please check if your host has the required amount of primary storage available.**

You can check this via UI and also through API.
Please use the API **listHosts** and pass the host id. You will be able to see total primary storage allocated, used and available.

**Same applies for RAM, CPU cores and secondary Storage.**